# Connect my web application to a web service

Tags: server, connection, wifi, port

In one hand, I have a server that I can connect to via Wifi (no Internet). With my browser, I can access the web service by a port number (192.168.x.x). In the other hand, I have a web application that I can access via the browser too on the localhost:*port*. I would like to access the data that is accessible by the 192.168.x.x port but via the web application. Do I need to add a new service, some new routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to add new route (you already can connect to web service so all routes already exists).
New service may make your job even harder, because you will need to configure communication between 3 differed applications.

Just edit your web application so it will take data from your web service.

Comment: Not sure to understand. Have to create a varriable in my app file that is copying the data of the web service, where I will configure it to connect to the port that is using the device?

Comment: Actual configuration is application dependent. It's hard to tell you how you how to configure app, without knowing what app.

Comment: The main file of my app is called app.js, so even without knowing what are the changes I have to make, it's probably in this file?

Comment: Looks like yes (I assume now that it is javascript application). It still depends on where this app actually executed.

If in browser then to get data from your server your just need to send XmlHTTPRequest. [Here is example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_httprequest.asp). 
If its nodejs app then it can be done by http.request. [here its documentation and example](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

Comment: I will take a look to the links and give you feedback. Thank you